# elasticsearch facet nested aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Using `elasticsearch 7.0.0`.

I am following this [link](https://project-a.github.io/on-site-search-design-patterns-for-e-commerce/#full-text-search).

I have an index `test_products` with following `mapping`:

```
{
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
},
"mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            "search_result_data": {
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "path_match": "search_result_data.*"
            }
        }
        ],
    "properties": {
        "search_data": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "full_text": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "string_facet": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "facet-name": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "facet-value": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And a document inserted with following format:

```
    {
  "search_result_data": {
    "sku": "wheel-6075-90092",
    "gtin": null,
    "name": "Matte Black Wheel Fuel Ripper",
    "preview_image": "abc.jg",    
    "url": "9836817354546538796",
    "brand": "Fuel Off-Road"
  },
  "search_data": 
    {
      "full_text": "Matte Black Wheel Fuel Ripper",
      "string_facet": [
        {
          "facet-name": "category",
          "facet-value": "Motor Vehicle Rims & Wheels"
        },
        {
          "facet-name": "brand",
          "facet-value": "Fuel Off-Road"
        }
      ]
    }    
}
```

and one other document..

I am trying to aggregate on `string_facet` as mentioned in the link.

```
"aggregations": {


"agg_string_facet": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "string_facet"
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "facet_name": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "string_facet.facet-name"
        },
        "aggregations": {
          "facet_value": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "string_facet.facet-value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get all (two) documents returned with :

```
"aggregations": {
    "agg_string_facet": {
      "doc_count": 0
   }
 }
```

What am I missing here?

Also why are the docs being returned as a response?

Comment: What are the results you are expecting? Would you like to get the unique values for facet-value and facet-name fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents are returned as a response because they match with your query.  If you'd like them to disappear, you can set the "size" field to 0. By default, it's set to 10.

```
query{
...
}, 
"size" = 0
```

I read the docs and [Facet aggregation has been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-facets-terms-facet.html). The recommendation is to use the [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

Now, for your question, you can go with two options:

1. If you'd like to get the unique values for each: facet-value and facet-name, you can do the following:

> 

```
"aggs":{
    "unique facet-values":{
        "terms":{
            "field": "facet-value.keyword",
            "size": 30 #By default is 10, maximum recommended is 10,000
        }
    },
    "unique facet-names":{
        "terms":{
            "field": "facet-name.keyword"
            "size": 30 #By default is 10, maximum recommended is 10,000
        }
    }
}
```

2. If you'd like to get the unique combinations between facet-name and facet-value, you can use the [Composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html). If you choose this way, your aggs should look like this:

> 

```
{
    "aggs":{
       "unique-facetvalue-and-facetname-combination":{
            "composite":{
                "size": 30, #By default is 10, maximum recommended is 10,000. No matter what size you choose, you can paginate.
                "sources":[
                    { 
                         "value":
                             { 
                                 "terms":{ 
                                     "field": "facet-value.keyword" 
                                  } 
                             } 
                    },
                    { 
                         "name":
                             { 
                                 "terms":{ 
                                     "field": "facet-name.keyword" 
                                  } 
                             } 
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of using Composite over Terms is that Composite lets you paginate your results with the [After key](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_after). So your cluster's performance does not get affected.

Hope this is helpful! :D